# Plugin with id 'com.google.gms:google-services' not found

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to add Firebase to my Android app, while syncing the project I got:

```
Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms:google-services' not found.
```

I added the dependencies, `google-services.json` file in app root, also I added Maven repo in build.gradle top level.

1/ `build.gradle` top project file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    allprojects {
        // ...
        repositories {
            // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
            google()  // Google's Maven repository
            // ...
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  // Google Services plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files}
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
        supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
        archRoomVersion = "1.0.0-alpha1"
    }
}
```

2/ `build.gradle` // app level

```
dependencies {
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.17'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'    
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        navigationVersion = '1.0.0-alpha09'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: Make sure you have all repositories in both allprojects.repositories and repositories blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apply plugin` is wrong. Should be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Notice the `.` between `com.google.gms` and `google-services`.

Also, just in case, `google()` should go before `jcenter()`.

Comment: okay I swapped them, but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: oohh, I see. I have just copied it from firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Could you mark the question as answered then?